# Do solid propellant engine needs optimum temperature?

Tags: rockets, propulsion

Do solid propellants have an optimum temperature to burn effectively?

If so, what is the range of temperature  needed?

Comment: Pressure is closely related to temperature. Perhaps this question should be linked http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/439/in-a-cryogenic-fuel-rocket-at-what-pressure-is-the-fuel-injected-into-the-engin

Comment: @Everyone its about optimum temperature and IMO both questions are not linked

Comment: Varies greatly based on propellant and engine types, a range is effectively meaningless in this broad context. "Optimum temperature" is unclear too, how broad of a range can still be an "optimum temperature"?